# how to fix navigator.permissions.query

Tags: javascript

I have a `navigator.permissions.query` that is **not** working

```
function handlePermission() {
  navigator.permissions.query({name:'geolocation'}).then(function(result) {
    if (result.state == 'granted') {
      report(result.state);
      geoBtn.style.display = 'none';
    } else if (result.state == 'prompt') {
      report(result.state);
      geoBtn.style.display = 'none';
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(revealPosition,positionDenied,geoSettings);
    } else if (result.state == 'denied') {
      report(result.state);
      geoBtn.style.display = 'inline';
    }
    result.onchange = function() {
      report(result.state);
    }
  });
}

function report(state) {
  document.getElementById("t").innerHTML = ('Permission ' + state);
}

handlePermission();
```

I have a live example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fxvstoqd/1/) please check out my code and tell me where I am going wrong

Comment: What is the expected output? Any error messages? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @BreakBB I want it to say granted or denied

Answer (score 0):

You should read [the example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API/Using_the_Permissions_API#Querying_permission_state) again and [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) for the functions you're using. The error messages in you live example are pretty clear.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(revealPosition,positionDenied,geoSettings);
```

You have to hand the correct/valid parameters to this function. `revealPosition` is a function which is run, when the user granted the geolocation, `positionDenied` is a function which is run, when the user denies the access to the geolocation and `geoSettings` is an object which includes the setting for the call to `.getCurrentPosition`.

So once you create the missing parameters instead of handing undefined references to the call the function will run just fine.

Comment: I have read that, but when I try to run their example it isn't working, please can you tell me what I am doing wrong look at the copy of that example https://jsfiddle.net/fxvstoqd/1/